# leetcode romantointeger problem syntax error every time

Tags: python

```py
class solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        ROMANS = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
        
        number = 0
        
        for i in range(len(s) - 1):
            if ROMANS[s[i + 1]]  > ROMANS[s[i]]:
                number -= ROMANS[s[i]]
            else:
                number += ROMANS[s[i]]
                
        number += ROMANS[s[len(s) - 1]]
        
        return number
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
^
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
Line 2  (Solution.py)

Comment: The syntax looks OK to me. Are you sure you're running it as "Python 3" and not as "Python"?

Comment: runned your code in both `python` as well as `python3` working fine!!